# findElement by class where content equals text

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate and click an element on my page but can't use the by.id method as the id's are generated and change per session. For most elements I can get around this by using xpath but there is a dropdown menu where this does not work. I can click the element containing the dropdown and it shows me the options. If I locate the element I need and copy it's xpath the test case won't function stating it can't find the xpath. Now next to the id the Element I'm trying to click also has a class. Problem is that this class is not unique, all menu items in the dropdown have the same class with a different text. What I would like to do is something like:

```
driver.findeElement(By.class("x-menu-item-text").equals("Unique text 1here").click()
```

The class "x-menu-item-text" is not unique but the text in this particular class is. I can't use the ID as this is automatically generated. The full code for the item or element I want to click is:

```
<a id="ext-comp-1035" class="x-menu-item" hidefocus="true" unselectable="on" href="#"><span id="ext-gen250" class="x-menu-item-text">Unique text 1 here</span></a>
<a id="ext-comp-1035" class="x-menu-item" hidefocus="true" unselectable="on" href="#"><span id="ext-gen250" class="x-menu-item-text">Unique text 2 here</span></a>
```

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Eclipse (Java).

Allthough the answer provided seems to work on most pages and locations, there is a situation however where I can't get it to work. Can anyone advise?
There is a page with buttons and I want to click one of these buttons. If I use the following statement:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Add']")).click();
```

I get an error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

If I look at the source I see:

```
<button class=" x-btn-text" id="ext-gen539" type="button">Add</button>
```

So the element is present and visible.
I've tried adding a wait.until statement before the click statement but this does not work either:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Toevoegen']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='Toevoegen']")).click();
```

**Extra information:** could this problem be because I'm looking for an element that is located in a popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath locator
https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators

By.xpath("//span[@class='x-menu-item-text' and text()='Unique text 1here']")

Comment: I've updated my question as I have trouble doing the same for another element and can't figure out why it's not working there

Comment: check id of the found object, is it correct object? (looks like you found another, duplicate element)
 findElement(By.xpath()).getAttribute("id")

Comment: If it's duplicate element, then fix xpath to find correct one, for example add parent relation: 
//popupwindow[@title='visible window']//span[@class='x-menu-item-text' and text()='Unique text 1here']